# Is が here a 格助 or 接助 element?

Tags: particle-が

Is が here a 格助 or 接助 element?

> 私の脈搏は普通1分間にやっと60なの**が**、80から85に増進していた。
>   My pulse, whose ordinary action is scarcely 60 beats to the minute, was accelerated to 80 or 85.

Comment: Could you explain why you think there is some ambiguity?

Comment: +1 but it would be an even better question if you told us what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「私の[脈搏]{みゃくはく}は[普通1分間]{ふつういっぷんかん}にやっと60**なのが**、80から85に[増進]{ぞうしん}していた。」

「なのが」 is ***three*** words here.

「な」: The [連体形]{れんたいけい} (attributive form) of the affirmation auxiliary verb 「だ」

「の」: [準体助詞]{じゅんたいじょし} (nominalization particle) = nominalizes the whole preceding phrase

「が」:「[格助詞]{かくじょし}」(case particle) = subject marker (← ***Answer to your question***)

The subject of this sentence is the fact that "***my heart rate is usually around 60 at the most***".

Then you insert the subject marker 「**が**」, and then comes the predicate.

The predicate is "***had shot up to the 80-85 range***".

Answer (score 1):

I  first think it is 接続助詞 because 格助詞 "が" is set the behind of a subject and I think 「普通1分間にやっと60なの」 isn't a subject. However after discussion, I knew a difference opinion. And I ask this question for some person, so their opinions are also be split into two.

In the result, my answer is that which one is possible depending on the standpoint.

Comment: でも・・・接続助詞の「が」なら、[『活用語の終止形に付』](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/34931/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8C/)くはずですし・・・「普通1分間にやっと60なの」は名詞の形ですし・・・

Comment: 主語が「私の脈拍は」と考えると接続助詞なのかと。間違っていたら消しますね。

Comment: 「は」は topic marker であって subject marker ではないですからね。。。意味から考えても違うと思いますよ。。。

Comment: 面白い意見もありました。もし、「なのが」は「なのだが」の「だ」が省略された形だとしたら、接続助詞だと思うと。色々な意見があるようです。

Comment: 「私の脈搏は普通1分間にやっと60なの**だ**が」「～～なの**です**が」なら、もちろん接続助詞で、上に貼った辞書の ❷[接助]２にあたります。「60なのが」は「60なのだが」の省略されたものではなく、そもそも異なる文でしょう。

Comment: 「普通1分間にやっと60なの」は、名詞の形ではないと思います。述語はどうしますか? 「普通1分間にやっと60なのが、増進していた。」ではおかしいですよね。
例えば、「泳ぐのが、うまい。」の「が」は格助詞だと思います。

Comment: この「の」は「準体助詞」っていうんです・・・ちゃんと辞書に載ってます・・・「～の」は名詞扱いだから、当然、「が」は格助詞ですよ。「泳ぐ**の**が、うまい」の「の」も、「６０な**の**が、～になってた。」の「の」も、準体助詞です。ですから当然、「泳ぐの**が**うまい」の「が」も、「６０なの**が** ～になってた。」の「が」も、格助詞のです。

Comment: もう少しいろいろな意見を聞きます。そうとは思わない意見もあるようです。私もまだ判断はつきかねます。

Comment: 論点を整理すると、「私の脈拍は普通1分間にやっと60なのが、80から85に増進していた。」の「なのが」が「なのだが」の「だ」の省略かどうかですね。省略だったら接続助詞、省略ではなかったら格助詞と。

では、比べてみましょう。
「私の脈拍は普通1分間にやっと60なのが、80から85に増進していた。」

「私の脈拍は普通1分間にやっと60なのだが、80から85に増進していた。」

どちらが自然ですか。私は後者だと思いますが。省略の可能性がある以上、接続助詞の可能性もあるわけです。別に私はどっちでもいいのですが、両方の可能性があるということです。